# Reshape model input LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Hello everyone i'm trying to build a model to predict emotion in speech.
Since the audio have different lengths the feature matrixes also have different lengths and therefore i have a variable timestep.
I read on other answers that i can leave the input shape of LSTM as follows: `model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(None, 31)))`

Next i need to reshape my input training data which it's a list of 2D arrays of variable timestep length (Tx,Features) into a list of 3D arrays of length (1,Tx,Features) for `Model.fit()`

I hope the logic behind what i'm doing is correct but anyhow i get an error when reshaping. I made sure that the types were correct, i don't know what could be the problem, here's the code:

```
def rnn(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):

    for e in x_train:
        print(type(e))
        print(type(e.shape[0]))
        print(type(e.shape[1]))
        x_train[e]=np.reshape(e,(1,e.shape[0],e.shape[1]))

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(None, 31)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)

    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/mp95/PycharmProjects/Thesis/Main.py", line 16, in <module>
    rnn(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
  File "C:\Users\mp95\PycharmProjects\Thesis\models.py", line 15, in rnn
    x_train[e]=np.reshape(e,(1,e.shape[0],e.shape[1]))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

Thank you very much, my dataset is small (450 examples) also any other tips on what should i do with the model it's very welcomed as i'm new to this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to this but from what I have found:
The input to LSTM is 3-D [samples,timesteps,features]
For more information, please visit this link :
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264546/difference-between-samples-time-steps-and-features-in-neural-network
Also I think that your problem is in this line
x_train[e]=np.reshape(e,(1,e.shape[0],e.shape[1]))
Maybe the dimensions are wrong